# changing username in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sudo, user-mode-linux

My terminal reads xyz@Sam .I want to change it to some name say Ema .
I tried usermod but everytime I get an error that this process is used by this process(some random four digit number ).

Comment: Are you using the Desktop version (has GUI) or the server version (no GUI)?

Comment: tried all not working it is saying this process is currently used

Comment: desktop version

Comment: You need to create a new temporary user with admin privileges. Log out of the user whose username you want to change and log in as the new user. Then try. You can't change the tires of a car while you drive it.